# Is there a way to declare a public static const that will be defined in the source file using constexpr (and what difference is there)?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constants, constexpr

In my header I have a public static const declared and I define in the source file as a class member.  I want to define it in the source file because I am including  and using a constant from an it, and I don't want to include  in my header.

If I use static constexpr in the header it requires a definition there.

header

```cpp
public:
  static const double DEG_TO_RADIANS;
```

source

```cpp
#include <math.h>

const double MyClass::DEG_TO_RADIANS = (M_PI/180.0);
```

Is this a situation where you just can't use constexpr, does this matter at all?

Why does a static const allow me to not define the variable but static constexpr doesn't?

Edit: The M_PI is a simple example of this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading the question right but with `static constexpr double DEG_TO_RADIANS = (M_PI/180.0);` you just need `constexpr double MyClass::DEG_TO_RADIANS;` in the source file.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: If you only intend to use it in one source file, define it there as `constexpr`, no need to declare it in the header.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't want to use an included constant in the header because I don't want to do the include in the header.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I want it to be public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of `constexpr` is to use it for values that can be known at compile time. That doesn't work if the definition is in a completely different file.

Static const requires you to provide a definition which a linker can connect between different files.

Comment: But doesn't static const have the same intent and effect and allow you to define it in the cpp? If not, does that mean there is no way to have a public variable defined at compile time in the cpp?

Comment: @Burnrate almost but not quite. Static const requires you to provide a definition which a linker can connect between different files.

Comment: So one will give me a slight, probably negligible, advantage in compile and load times and the other will give the same in run time.  If I don't want to include something in my header then static const it is, otherwise I will go with static constexpr.  I think I understand now, thank you.